# when we debug code that time upload all images but when upload through webservice that time upload only one or two image in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

In this code only one image is uploaded when code runs through publish webservice, but when I run code in debug mode, it will upload all images.

```
foreach (ClsImage ima in objInvoice.images)
{
    string OTPNumber = Common.getRandomString();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ima.Image))
    {
        string pathAndFile = Common.GetFilePath(Config.InvoicesImagePath, Convert.ToDateTime(lvar), OTPNumber, objInvoice.StoreID, objInvoice.UserID) + Config.InvoicesImageFormat;
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Directory.GetParent(pathAndFile).ToString());
        if (File.Exists(pathAndFile))
        {
            File.Delete(pathAndFile);
        }
        string retVal = Common.SaveToFile(ima.Image, pathAndFile);
        if (retVal != "Success")
        {
            Common.WriteErrorLog("Unable to save file: " + "");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not uploaded multiple only one image was upload please help me above

Comment: Maybe some filesystem permission issues? You should see some error details in windows eventlog. Or try to catch any Exception by writing it to a file.